# Django templates don't load, even though the url changes

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-views

I have spent so much time trying to solve this issue but don't know where the problem lies since there are no errors popping up. It simply doesn't work.

```
mysite/
manage.py
mysite/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
Home/
    templates/
        Home/
            Home.html
Application/
    templates/
        Application/
            Apply.html
```

In my Home.html I have a link:

```
<a href="{% url 'Application:Apply' %}">Apply Now!</a>
```

When I click on it, the url changes to /Apply but I remain on the same page. (It also seems like the Home.html is getting reloaded since I need to scroll down the page to click on that link and once I click it, it gets me back to the top of the page).

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), 
    url(r'^', include('Application.urls', namespace = 'Application')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,         
document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Home/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.Home, name = 'Home'),
]
```

Application/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

app_name = "Application"
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'Apply', views.Apply, name = 'Apply'),
]
```

Application/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def Apply(request):
    return render(request, 'Application/Apply.html')
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice since I cannot move on with my project until I figure that out.

Comment: Show the urls.py in Home.

Comment: I've just added them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the end-of-string character `'$'` in your `Home` url, so the pattern *intercepts* every other url since they all match the start character `'^'`. Add an end-of-string character:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.Home, name = 'Home'),
]
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('^', 'Apply')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1034c9b90>
>>> re.match('^$', 'Apply')
>>>
```